# Getting at XML tree data in perl

Tags: perl, xml-simple

I need to parse an XML file using perl which I can load the file using the XML::Simple module but within the XML tree there is a tag that I can't see using the DataDumper module but I can see it's value instead.

```
    <testcase id="10">
        .
        .
        .
    </testcase>
```

Above is a Sample of the XML file with the testcase tag. It's the  part that I have difficulty with. Using DataDumper to view the contents of the array I see something like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'testcases' => {
                         'file' => 'testcases.xml',
                         'testcase' => {
                                       '10' => {
                                                },
```

Since the XML is defined like  why isn't it layed out in the VAR1 array with the id included? Instead of expecting testcases->testcase->id I get testcases->testcase->10. Which 10 is the id but what happened to the 'id' tag?

Comment: `id` is not a `tag`, it is an `attribute`.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at `XML::Twig` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. XML::Twig looks interesting and I may look into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the default config includes

```
KeyAttr => [qw( name key id )]
```

Specifying

```
KeyAttr => []
```

will cause `id` to be no different than any other attribute.

Comment: you right, it is an attribute. Boy I've not worked with XML in awhile. I think I need a refresher. Thanks for the pointer.